# Retrieve the "Uncategorized" default WooCommerce Category ID

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to get the "**Uncategorized**" default WooCommerce plugin category id.

I would say that since it is the first category that is created by default, the id would be 1, `term_id = 1`, but it is not the case.

I also tried:

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'parent'     => 0, // to get only parent terms
    'fields'     => 'id=>name',
);
$terms = get_terms( $args );
```

But it returns all terms. I need only the ID (`term_id`) of the "**Uncategorized**" default Category create by WooCommerce upon activation.

Is there a function like `get_default_cat_id()` or similar? I cannot use `'name__like' => 'Uncategorized'` because the name 'Uncategorized' could be changed to something else.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `'name__like' => 'Uncategorized'`?

Comment: Yes, but what about if the name is changed to something else? That is why it is best to retrieve it by ID or similar. Any thought?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's saved as an option under the name `default_product_cat`. To get the ID you can call `get_option()`

```
$uncategorized_term_id = get_option( 'default_product_cat' );
```

Comment: Thank you very much pal. It helped me a lot. I appreciate it